# Akka.io: Thread per Actor

Tags: scala, akka

There is a requirement to run 1 thousand operations asynchoniosly, I've chosen to use Akka.
Warpping in Actor Ref executor and sending 1 thousand messages to ref.

How can I be sure that:

- all 1 thousand messages will be dispatched in asnc way
- each will hold the separate, in-depended thread (that is requirement because of io usage).

Comment: can't you use nio ? Akka has PinnedDispatcher for this but recommand to not block actor.

Comment: Why do you think, that IO requires seperate threads? With NIO you only need to attach a thread to a resource, when data is available. Could you please clarify? Also having 1000 threads running in a single application may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `PinnedDispatcher` to guarantee one thread per actor, and everything in Akka is async, so you can be guaranteed the messages are async.  If you send your messages using the `!` operator, the message is sent in a fire-and-forget manner.

See [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html) for more details.

Comment: I suggest you remove your last sentence, because if an actor blocks during message processing like it seems to be the case here because of blocking (?) IO, then it is not correct to say "nothing will block".

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [PinnedDispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#Types_of_dispatchers)

Configuration example & code is [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#More_dispatcher_configuration_examples)

No blocking until bounded mailbox will be used

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses, actually for my case combination of 
RoundRobinRouter (where number of routes is equal to number of expected threads) and PinnedDispatcher with flag thread-pool-executor.allow-core-timeout=off is working fine.