# Akka: running Slf4jEventHandler on a dedicated thread

Tags: multithreading, logging, akka, actor

I use `Slf4jEventHandler` for logging in an Akka 2.0.5 app:

```
akka {
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"

  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    default-dispatcher {
      mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
    }
  }

  # ...
}
```

How should the config be updated so that the actor that handles logging runs on a dedicated thread? I suspect I'd need to set up a pinned dispatcher and deploy the slf4j actor onto it, but am not sure how exactly to configure it, so a complete config example would be ideal.

Comment: Interesting question.  For any actor you start yourself, you can specify a separate dispatcher, so if you were the one who started the logging actor then conceivable you could set up a Pinned dispatcher so it ran on its own thread.  I wonder if you can hook into where akka starts up the logging actor to override the dispatcher it uses

Comment: This previous question may be helpful: [Akka.io: Thread per Actor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160324/akka-io-thread-per-actor)